# Group by a column that uses a substring fails when there is no result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a CTE that uses a SUBSTRING to get a value for a column.
That substring is build up with some combined functions (REVERSE, CHARINDEX) to get the correct position and length. A query that uses this CTE, puts that column in a GROUP BY.

This works good. But not if there is no result at all in the CTE.

Then, I get this error:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

I see this message a lot on stackoverflow, but not for this situation. Does anyone know this problem, and what can I do about it?

To illustrate my problem, some simplified code without the REVERSE functions:

```
;WITH #mycte AS(
SELECT p.[CreatedDate] AS CreatedDate, 
SUBSTRING(p.[value], 
     CHARINDEX('starttag', p.[value])+16, 
      (CHARINDEX('endtag', p.[value] - CHARINDEX('starttag', p.[value])
) AS Remark

SELECT COUNT(*), CreatedDate, Remark FROM #mycte GROUP BY Remark
```

Comment: Note: The starttag and endtag do always exist if there are records, so the query can't fail. Only in this situation when there is no result at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you'd need to change:

```
p.[value]
```

To:

```
ISNULL(p.[Value],0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :-) I was focussing on the length and position params because of the message, but it was the first..